# How to call another's file function in a module function on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to call these function written on ***apiGet.js*** file:

```
export let apiGet = () => {
    return 'File One';
}
```

It's called on another module named ***brand.js*** file, this is the code:

```
require("../actions/apiGet.js");

const sendGetRequest = () => {
    console.log(apiGet());
};

module.exports = sendGetRequest();
```

After executed, there is an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: apiGet is not defined
```

How to solve this?

Comment: `const { apiGet } = require(...);`? Although you seem to be mixing module systems.

Comment: It works, you save my time. Thank you so much.

Comment: Now I realize that term { apiGet } means a function name inside apiGet.js. If we have another functions inside file apiGet.js, it should be called { apiGet, anotherFunction }.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { apiGet } from './actions';
```

Something like that should work. The path will change depending on where actions is of course.